# controllers are placed in the wrong position

Tags: ios, autolayout

In the storyboard I dragged a button and a label almost to the center to the of the scene as shown in image-1, button in the simulator, both the controllers are placed at the top left as shown in image-2.

please let me know why the controllers are placed on the wrong position despite I used layout constraints

**image-1**:

[image]

**image-2**:

[image]

**update section**:

i placed the two outlets inside a stack view, and set constrains as shown in image-3 below, but this time nothing appears on the screen at all.

**image-3**:

[image]

Comment: Why is a backward arrow in First View Controller? You cannot do like this.

Comment: @AnuragSharma because I have 3 scenes "1,2,3" and i transit from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3 and then from 3 to 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center both label and button and you want a space between them, do use **stackView** for this.

**How:**

1.Put 2 outlets in stackView and center align that stackView.

2.Now change settings of stackView like this.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** if you center align by using top,right bottom and left constraint you have to handled it programmatically to support all device.
As and example, if i use Top,Left, Bottom and Right and see the changes in iphone SE the output will look like this.

[image]

To center align from storyboard.

[image]

Just click on **Add 2 constraints** button.:) Before that remove your previous contraints.

Comment: please have a look at the update section i posted above

Comment: you want to center aligned stack view.So don't use top right bottom left.
why? because suppose you are designing it for iphone 5 layout and your simulator is iphone 7 in that case it will give you abnormal result just like now.
so  from align tab, just select horizontally in container vertically in container

Comment: @where can i find horizontally and vertically in container?

Comment: i have edited my answer.Pls check. and if it's helpful hope you'll accept my answer then. :)

Comment: actually, i did what you suggested ..but still the outlets are not showing on the simulator